# Hugo produces URL's for content sections. How do I stop that?

Tags: hugo

How do I produce content in Hugo that doesn't produce a page?

On my homepage I have an accordion that lists the services the company provides and when clicked provides a short summary and an image. To do this I have created the following in the `content/` directory:

```
content/
  services/
    img/
      kitchens.png
      bathrooms.png
      ...
    kitchens.md
    bathrooms.md
    upvc-doors.md
    ...
    index.md
```

Inside the `index.md`:

```
---
title: "Company Name"
---

A description for the services section on the homepage
```

The problem is in the generated sitemap it's producing paths for all of the sections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/index/</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-11-06T21:17:40+00:00</lastmod>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/footer/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/about/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/categories/</loc>
    <priority>0</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/contact/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/</loc>
    <priority>0</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/services/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/clients/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/gallery/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/tags/</loc>
    <priority>0</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/accreditations/</loc>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://example.co.uk/operating-areas/</loc>
  </url>

</urlset>
```

Many of these pages I do not need such as `accreditations`, and `services` as this content is solely used by my custom template to load the `index.md` from each directory and display it in the section. I use leaf bundles to store the images for each section so this way of organising content makes sense.

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong but i can't figure out what it is. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by zwbetz on the Hugo forums: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-do-i-create-pages-that-do-not-produce-a-physical-page/15542

> [Headless bundles](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/#headless-bundle) may meet your needs